# extension point doesn´t return

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp

I have a rcp app.After upgrading to RTC version 4.0.5 from version 2.0,

```
Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getExtensionPoint
```

doesn´t return all extension points in maven test.
But if I start my app as a hosted-plugin of Eclipse IDE, all extension points are returned.

Someone knows why ? Any suggestions are accepted

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your plugins resolved state  in maven environment ?

here are the steps open open OSGi console 
enter command ss 
it will show list of all plugins please make sure your all plugin should resolved ...

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted my fragment project and created a new one with different name. and it worked! I can not say what was wrong with the previous one.